# How to find the derivative of a function in the direction from point to point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How can I find the derivate of a function? This is the exercise:
$z = x^3 - 3y^3$ at $M(3;1)$ in the direction from point $M$ to point $K(6;5)$.

Comment: Hi, so you have *two points* can we construct a vector with that information? You can write in your post your work, inclusive the definition the directional derivative. All your work is important.  I think you may be stuck with the "unusual" information in the problem about points, however I hope my first question redirects your work.

Comment: I used the second point (6;5) to construct a vector and I am stuck with the vector being (6/ sqr(61); 5/ sqr(61)). At that point I think I should take the first point (3;1) and calculate the first derivatives?

Comment: Don't worry, I should recommend you that you add your work in the post-question. It's important to show your work here in MSE.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= 3x^2$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}= -9y^2/$ so $\nabla z= 3x^2\vec{i}- 9y^2\vec{j}$.  At (3, 1) that is $\nabla z(3,1)= 27\vec{i}- 9\vec{j}$.

The derivative in the direction of $6\vec{i}+ 5\vec{j}- (3\vec{i}+ \vec{j})= 3\vec{i}+ 4\vec{j}$ is $(27\vec{i}- 9\vec{j})\cdot (3\vec{i}+ 4\vec{j})= 81- 36= 45$.

Answer (score 0):

First define $f(x,y)=x^{3}-3y^{3}$. Now, I suppose that your question is about the *directional derivatives* so you need:

1. A unit vector for the direction.
2. One point.

We have two points but the problems say "at $M(3;1)$" for the context so that point will be $(a,b)=(3,1)$.

We can construct the vector for the direction as
$$\vec{v}=(6-3)\vec{i}+(5-1)\vec{j}=3\vec{i}+4\vec{j}$$
because the direction is "from point $M(3;1)$ to point $K(6;5)$".

The unit vector can be find directly by definition,
$$\vec{u}=\frac{\vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3^{2}+4^{2}}}(3\vec{i}+4\vec{j})=\frac{3}{5}\vec{i}+\frac{4}{5}\vec{j}$$

So we have all the necessary information and in this point you can go to two approach:

1. Find the directional derivatives using the definition, i.e., $$D_{\vec{u}}f(a,b)=\lim_{t\to 0; t>0}\frac{f((a,b)+t\vec{u})-f(a,b)}{t}$$
2. Find the directional derivatives using the following result,
   $$D_{\vec{u}}f(a,b)=\nabla f(a,b)\cdot \vec{u}$$ where $\cdot$ denote the dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $\nabla f(a,b)$ denote the gradient in the point $(a,b)$.

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I followed this solution using the second example because it seems more familiar with me. However I get to the point where the answer is 30 and at the textbook its written 9

Comment: Please add in your post the picture of the textbook (the question and answer). For the numerical answer see the Georgy Ivey's post.